# AWK: elegant way to deal with multiple delimiter criteria

Tags: regex, awk

I am processing log files with awk. Some lines are like:

> [TIME] [TYPE] entryA:a entryB:b entryC:{c1: val1, c2: val2}

All primary fields are like `name:value` or `name:{subentries}`(subentries have space after colon).
So far I could use space delimiter to process normal entries or use regex to match content within {}, and extract data if it contains subentries(say, `/([^\s]*:\s[^\s]*),/`). But not all the {} blocks contain subentries, and for some reason I think it is better to seperate the processing of primary entries and subentries.

Is it possible to extract all primary fields at once?

**EDIT:**

I want to expect an output a list of primary entries like:

> entryA entryB entryC

Also, I want to know if it is possible to maintain an array to record that if an entry has its own subentries.

Comment: Please add expected output in your post too and let us know then.

Comment: add a few lines of concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Or with `sed` following may help you, tested on Input_file mentioned this post itself in first attempt.

```
sed 's#entry[A-Z]:{.*}##g;s#\[TIME\] ##;s#\[TYPE\] ##'  Input_file
```

---

Since you have not mentioned expected output in your post, so based on your mentioned summary only have written the code, which will remove all the values which have `{c1: val1, c2: val2}` in lines and print the all other values.

Let's say following is Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
[TIME] [TYPE] entryA:a entryB:b entryC:{c1: val1, c2: val2} entryA:a entryB:b
```

Then following is the code for this:

```
awk '
{
   while($0) {
      match($0,/entry[a-zA-Z]+:{[^}]*\}/)
      val=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
      gsub(/\[TYPE\] |\[TIME\] /,"",val)
      if(RSTART>1) {
         printf("%s",val)
      }
      if(RSTART && RLENGTH) {
         $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
      }
      else {
         printf("%s\n",substr($0,pre_start+pre_end+1))
         next
      }
      prev_start=RSTART
      prev_end=RLENGTH
   }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
entryA:a entryB:b entryA:a entryB:b
```

Comment: hope you don't mind but I know you struggle with what style of indentation to adopt so I updated your script to use one of the common styles to make the control flow much clearer and so you can see how to do it from here on out. You could remove all the extraneous `;`s too if you want to tidy it up more. I didn't upvote because the OP hasn't provided a [mcve] yet so I've no idea if your answer addresses her problem (eg what does `Is it possible to extract all primary fields at once?` mean?) in a reasonable way or not.

Comment: @EdMorton, mind to your edit NOT at all possible, please always do so Ed. Those `;` semi colons came since I always write first one liner and then convert them to non-one liner :) yeah even I agree too, waiting for OP to come back on did this helped or not, cheers and happy Sunday :)